# Windows 10 (UEFI) does not boot from grub [dual boot] after Ubuntu upgrade

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, grub, dualboot

I had Windows 10 and Ubuntu which were working without any issues until I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. Now I cannot access Windows from the options in the grub menu. Nothing happens when I select any of them (besides Ubuntu). Secure Boot is disabled.

[image: GRUB]

Here is everything I tried:

1. I reintsalled Windows 10 with a USB installer media and the new Windows installation worked. But when I change the BOOT sequence to have Ubuntu first, I am left with the same problem.
2. Disabled Fast startup in Windows
3. Tried the solution offered by Hermes and the one by Carolus & Philippe Gachoud [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows)
4. Boot repair (recommended repair) which only added a new entry in grub: Windows (UEFI) which when selected does nothing.

Please help. How can I remove all the options in the grub menu which are not needed and add one which lets me boot into Windows?

Comment: Windows updates often turn fast start up back on. Double check it is off. Some have had to run chkdsk even if no errors shown to repair NTFS.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to edit grub is with `grub-customizer`, a GUI for editing grub.

From a Linux terminal enter

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

after installation completes enter

`$ sudo grub-customizer`

You will be able to change your boot order and other settings and options for grub. When you're satisfied with your configuration click `Save` and your grub config will be updated, and any bootable partitions will also be added.

However, you said you reinstalled Windows after you installed Linux. Installing Linux before installing Windows can cause boot issues, normally you will want to install Windows first, then Linux. I personally install them on separate drives so installation order doesn't matter unless I'm installing on a laptop, which typically only has one drive.